# Which IP addresses are not routed via Tor?

Tags: network-configuration, ip-address

Does Tor have any filter for specific IP-adresses?

For example, the [FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#DefaultExitPorts) lists some of the [reserved IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses) as being blocked by the default exit policy.

Is there an extra filter?

Comment: An exit node can apply its own exit policy filter, so this question is not answerable generally.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Thank you. It is enough to know that this is only handled via exit policy, and there are no extra filters. (If you want an accept and upvote, you can post this as an answer).